# How do we define the context menu in FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

While I could define the ContextMenu without the FXML, I do not find a good way to define the context menu in FXML:

In source file:

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
contextMenu.getItems().addAll(someMenuItems);
// This runs perfectly
```

In FXML:

```
<ContextMenu fx:id="contextMenu">
</ContextMenu>
// This is incorrect in fxml. The Exception of "Unable to coerce javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu to class javafx.scene.Node" is thrown.

<MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
    //... Some Menu and items could be defined here
</MenuBar>
// This is correct in fxml
```

I understand that MenuBar works because it extends javafx.scene.control.Control that is a subclass of javafx.scene.Node but ContextMenu does not.

So is there any way to define properties of ContextMenu similarly in FXML?

Comment: I know some people prefer coding FXML manually to using Scene Builder, but if don't know how to do certain things manually then just use Scene Builder for that part and then see how the FXML is generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to define it in the corresponding Node context (no pun intended :) through the `contextMenu` property:

```
<TextField fx:id="tf">
    <contextMenu>
        <ContextMenu fx:id="cmTF">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Add"/>
                <MenuItem text="Remove"/>
                <MenuItem text="Enhance"/>
            </items>
        </ContextMenu>
    </contextMenu>
</TextField>
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't notice that contextMenu is in fact a property inside the Node!

Comment: @DauZi only for Node of type Control, otherwise you should use the other method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53395237/536418)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<BorderPane fx:id="borderPane" fx:controller="sample.Controller" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <fx:define>
        <ContextMenu fx:id="contextMenu">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Menu Item"/>
            </items>
        </ContextMenu>
    </fx:define>
</BorderPane>
```

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ContextMenu contextMenu;

    @FXML
    private BorderPane borderPane;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        borderPane.setOnContextMenuRequested(event -> {
            contextMenu.show(borderPane, event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is more for "how to create a context menu for anything else that is not a Control" , but fortunately that was exactly what I was looking for ;-)
Thank you